# Visual Studio marks data type as syntax error?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Well, I've opened a solution I worked on previously (without any errors), and suddenly VB.NET finds "errors" in *data types*. What could possibly cause this? The code compiled before, without any syntax errors. A review by a few colleagues also didn't point out any other errors in the code. It also breaks on `er` in `Integer`, suddenly ignores `End While` even though they match and a whole bunch of other non-errors. I've tried re-formatting the code, reinstalling Visual Studio etc. Something in the code is causing this, but I have no idea how this is even possible.

[image: error demonstration]

*Example 1*

[image]

*Example 2*

Comment: Have you tried a clean and rebuild?  You might also try deleting your bin and obj folders if the clean doesn't fix it.

Comment: @JohnKoerner Done that. Same error(s).

Comment: Just a shot in the dark.  If you go to the references for your project are any of them listed with a yellow exclamation box?

Comment: Have you tried an loading an [experimental instance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166560.aspx) and loading the project in there?  If that doesn't work, I would suggest trying to repair visual studio.

Comment: @JohnKoerner Yeah, tried that, too ... . Repair VS is a good idea in theory, but it does yield the same results. Maybe I'm hitting some limits of LOCs inside a single Module.

Comment: Try the report a smile/frown button.  I've gotten responses from the VS team on those and they have been helpful.  Usually takes a few days to a week though.

Comment: @JohnKoerner Guess there nothing else to try. I expected to have a variety of problems - but not this...

Comment: Does the code look sensible when viewed from an external text editor? Can you copy the code from the IDE to a text editor and then back into a new class and see if the new class triggers errors?

Comment: @Mort Yes the code looks fine with other editors. (Tried SciTE, NP++ and VSC).

Comment: @minxomat how about the same class in a different project? And on a different workstation?

Comment: @Mort There are no classes. This is one module and it breaks this way on every Windows 10 system I tried. Both in VS13 and VS15. I'm now convinced this is a bug and reported it, I'll update my question when I get a response.

Comment: @minxomat did you get to the bottom of this?

Comment: Try commenting out the code, rebuilding, and uncommenting. Also, try removing and adding your references. Delete your entire project and re-download the trunk (if applicable). Try Build > Clean, **before** doing a Rebuild. This sometimes makes a difference in my projects.

Comment: Pretty sure it's just the parser got messed up, and you have to get it to re-parse your code.